# logged user does not have all fields filled up

Tags: php, symfony, session, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 2.8 and Doctrine and I have security.yml configured to point to the **User** class which implements **UserInterface**.
My ORM schema is in YAML.

The problem:

- In database the user has also specified "email" field, Symfony for LOGGED USER is not filling up that field and also "password" field is empty.

[image: screenshot]

When I do `$this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->clear(User::class);`
then the entity manager is fetching correctly the entity.
But when the entity is COMING FROM SESSION, then it's incorrect.

The problem is also that when I try to fetch a fresh entity from database using find() on a repository then, the incorrect element from session is fetched when I will not use the `$em->clear(User::class)`

How to tell Symfony/Doctrine to construct my entity in that way that it will have all fields filled up, so it will become persistable?

```
<?php

namespace XXX\AppBundle\Model\Entity;

use XXX\AppBundle\Model\Entity\Server\Logging;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * User
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $username
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var string $email
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var string $password
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @var array $roles
     */
    protected $roles = array();

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $logEvents
     */
    protected $logEvents;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $username
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles or permissions granted to the user for security.
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;

        // guarantees that a user always has at least one role for security
        if (empty($roles)) {
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        }

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // See "Do you need to use a Salt?" at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html
        // we're using bcrypt in security.yml to encode the password, so
        // the salt value is built-in and you don't have to generate one

        return;
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        $this->password = null;
        $this->email    = null;
    }

    /**
     * Appends an entry to administration log
     *
     * @param \XXX\AppBundle\Model\Entity\Server\Logging $logEvent
     * @return $this
     */
    public function appendLog(Server\Logging $logEvent)
    {
        if (!$this->logEvents->contains($logEvent))
        {
            $this->logEvents->add($logEvent);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a log entry from the history
     *
     * @param \XXX\AppBundle\Model\Entity\Server\Logging $logEvent
     * @return $this
     */
    public function clearLogEntry(Server\Logging $logEvent)
    {
        $this->logEvents->removeElement($logEvent);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And ORM configuration:

```
XXX\AppBundle\Model\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: users
    repositoryClass: XXX\AppBundle\Model\Repository\UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            scale: 0
            length: null
            unique: false
            nullable: false
            precision: 0
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        username:
            type: string
            scale: 0
            length: null
            unique: true
            nullable: false
            precision: 0
        email:
            type: string
            scale: 0
            length: null
            unique: true
            nullable: false
            precision: 0
        password:
            type: string
            scale: 0
            length: null
            unique: false
            nullable: false
            precision: 0
        roles:
            type: json_array
            scale: 0
            length: null
            unique: false
            nullable: false
            precision: 0
    oneToMany:
        logEvents:
            targetEntity: XXX\AppBundle\Model\Entity\Server\Logging
            cascade:
                - remove
                - persist
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: author
            inversedBy: null
            orphanRemoval: false
            orderBy: null
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: How are you retrieving your user from the session, what is the code in your User class?

Comment: Yes, I'm retrieving the user from the session.

In user class I have just protected private properties + getters.
And the ORM yml file looks normally like in other entities.

Comment: Please post code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VkyRDHXx
http://pastebin.com/CNQf8dCd
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implemented the UserInterface::eraseCredentials() method in a way that it unsets the email and the password:

```
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    $this->password = null;
    $this->email    = null;
}
```

Symfony will invoke this method before serializing the object to save it in the session.

The UserInterface::eraseCredentials() is meant to remove sensitive data from the user object so it does not end up in for example the session files, but there is no real need to remove the email, like you are doing. A better example would be if you are storing the plaintext version of the user's password somewhere on this object, this is something you would never want to end up in session files.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not removing the username, but just password and e-mail :)

Comment: How to implement the password change or role list change when e-mail or password is erased?

Comment: Right, but that's why the email is missing when retrieving from the session.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with that question @KrzysztofaKrzysztof

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I will have probably to detach the logged user in password edit form and operate on a fresh object from database.

Comment: I mean I have a user profile page, and a password change form, roles assignment. I will have to probaby detach the previous entity, fetch a fresh one and then persist the second one. But I have also implemented logging of administrative actions in administration panel, its triggered in a "Manager" class, will have to do something to restore previous entity for logging.

Comment: You probably will always want to retrieve (or refresh) the user object in the entity manager when you are getting it from the session. You could even entirely split up your UserInterface implementation from the user entity, having 2 entirely separate classes (separation of concerns, yay).

Comment: So, what do you mean in this context by the separation of concerns?
Could you a little bit point the concept here?

Comment: Goes a bit beyond the scope of this question, but basically I have 2 user classes, my entity and one implementing the UserInterface (and just the UserInterface). The rest of the magic happens in my custom UserProvider, which will load my user entity (based on the username), and then instantiate and return an instance of my class implementing the UserInterface, using any data it needs from my user entity.